# Is it possible to create a binary that can run on both windows and linux

Tags: binaryfiles

As the title said, with any possible tricks or bugs,can we create a binary file can run both on Linux and Windows without any change?
(The file must be directly created by a compiler)

I know it's nearly impossible,but with some tricky methods,is that possible?

Comment: You can do this with Java, C#, or other languages that require a runtime environment to run. Of course both Windows and Linux users will have to install the runtime if it doesn't come with the operating system by default.

Comment: Of cource,but is it possible to create a binary file with PE and ELF structure inside and can run with just a few changes to the system